# Utilzando rsync con patrones (patterns)

Tags: archivo, linux, rsync

¿Cómo puedo hacer copias de solamente los archivos cuyos nombres son semejantes a unos [patrones (*patterns*)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15506/c%C3%B3mo-se-dice-pattern-en-espa%C3%B1ol-cuando-refiere-a-una-b%C3%BAsqueda-de-semejanzas/15507#15507)? He intentado usar `rsync`, pero o no se copia nada o se copia todo. Estas preguntas en SO en inglés no me sirvieron:

1. [rsync include-from problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449306/rsync-include-from-problems)
2. [Using Rsync include and exclude options to include directory and file by pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952000/using-rsync-include-and-exclude-options-to-include-directory-and-file-by-pattern)

Aquí hay algunos de mis intentos de hacerlo:

- Todo en la línea de comandos (command line):

  ```
  rsync -rv --include='solexa/' --include='solexa/*/*.csv' --exclude='*' solexa RunMetrics
  ```
- Con un archivo de patrones:

  ```
  rsync -av --include-from patrones.txt solexa RunMetrics
  ```

  Aquí está mi archivo de patrones (*patterns*) cuando no se copia nada. Quiero copiar solamente los archivos con nombres que empiezan con un número:

  ```
  + ^\d.*/*.csv
  - *
  ```

  Aquí está mi archivo de "*patterns*" cuando se copia todo:

  ```
  + */*.csv
  ```

No me importa si se hace con `rsync` o con otra herramienta, solamente pensaba que `rsync` tenía las capacidades para hacerlo.

Comment: Tiene que ser con rsync? En que OS estás?

Comment: @JuanK Linux. Gracias por preguntar. No tiene que ser `rsync`.

Answer (score 2):

- Parece que no se usa `\d` en este tipo de patrón, pero el patr:on `[0-9]` corresponde bien a los números (como se utiliza en `bash`).
- También, hay que incluir patrones para [todos los directorios por encima de los archivos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862508/how-to-rsync-file-pattern-in-subfolders) requeridos (y todavía hay que incluir `/` al final del patrón de los directorios):

Estos patrones funcionan para corresponder a los archivos deseados:

```
+ [0-9].*/
+ [0-9].*/*.csv
- *
```

Answer (score 0):

Y generando previante un fichero con el contenido de todo lo que quieres...

Algo así:

```
$ find . -iname "[0-9]*" -exec echo "fichero " {} >> /tmp/lista_ficheros \;
```

Luego lo puedes incluir/usar en el rsync mediante el parametro **--files-from**

```
$ rsync ....  --files-from=/tmp/lista_ficheros** ....
```